# Why total differential(df) of a scalar function is a contravariant vector?

Tags: functions, differential-geometry, vectors, tensors

Our professor in our college while teaching tensor analysis basics told that for a scalar function $f$ of $n$ variables $x^1, x^2,...x^n$, the total differential of $f$ is a contravariant vector.
It was given as an example for contravariant vectors.
But after trying to prove the result myself, I failed. I cannot understand how to prove it using the transformation rule for contravariant vector.
Any response will be of great help. Thankyou!

Comment: You should add the definition of a contravariant vector and the definition of $df$.

Comment: False, $df$ is the gradient in covariant form

Answer (score 0):

Usually one associates with each 0-form $f\in C^\infty_p$ a unique element $df \in T^*_p=\Lambda^1(T_p(M))$ s.t $d:\,\,\Lambda^0\to\Lambda^1$. The components of the gradient, $f_j=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}$, can (with some abuse of notation) be regarded as the components of a **covariant vector**. The sum $df=f_jdx^j$ is called a 1-form (or Pfaffian form). This 1-form happens to be a scalar; however, given a type $(1,1)$ tensor field $A^h_j$ one can similarly define other 1-forms by constructing the expressions $A^h_jdx^j$ and those are actually called **contravariant 1-forms**. In particular, with $A^h_j=\delta^h_j$ we obtain the the familiar *1-forms* $dx^h$. Maybe this naming convention is part of the confusion?

Comment: This naming conventions are the strangest I have ever seen. Both in differential geometry and physics, I have seen "contravariant" been used to denote vectors and (informally) "objects with upstairs indices".

Maybe you are correct about this terminology but I would explain in more detail as it is highly nonstandard.

Comment: One is often confronted with k-forms which are not scalars. For example, in the notation of E. Cartan, "the covariant exterior derivative of the  *contravariant 2-form* $\Omega^j=A_{h\,\,k}^{\,\,j}dx^h\wedge dx^k$ is $D\Omega^j=d\Omega^j+\Omega^h\wedge\omega_h^{\,\,j}$ which is a *contravariant 3-form*". I think it is taking it a bit too far saying the traditional notation of giants like Cartan, Kobayashi and Nomizu is the strangest thing you have ever seen or to consider it highly non-standard.

Comment: I apologize if I took the expression too far. I come from a more physical background and I have associated "scalars" with functions $C^\infty$. In the excerpt you quoted: is this *contravariant 2-form* simply a tensor of mixed type (2-covariant, 1-contravariant) which happens to be skew-symmetric in the covariant entries, or is there something else going on? By this I mean, maybe $\Omega$ refers to a Lie-algebra valued form, or maybe even with values in another vector bundle.

Comment: @ContraKinta This is the first time we are studying Differential Geometry and have just been introduced to contravariant and covariant vectors. I did not understand the terminologies that you have used in you answer. We have not read any of these till now. But I think you want to tell that df is not contravariant when we consider the transformation rules but contravariant in some other sense. Am I right?